# WP8 Calendar store like contact store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I've built a windows phone 8 application.

As of today, I can synchronize contacts from the internet with contacts on the phone thanks to the [contact store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207024%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Everything is ok.

Do we have the same thing for the calendar so that our appointments will be visible in the calendar of the phone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is an [Appointment Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentstore.aspx) class. Through the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263359) namespace, you can create and manage appointments in a user's calendar app. Here you can create an appointment, add it to a calendar app, replace it in the calendar app, and remove it from the calendar app.

*Pre-requisite:* Before you can use any of the app calendar APIs you need to update your app manifest. In Solution Explorer, double-click Package.appxmanfest to open the manifest designer. On the Capabilities tab, check the Appointments capability

Here are some other links that you can check out:

1) [Managing Appointments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn495339.aspx)

2) [Managing App Calenders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631243.aspx)

3) [Reading Data from App Calenders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631245.aspx)